# Як правильно сказати - "Стаття потребує правок"

Tags: іменники

На сайті [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/)

> Замініть іменник правка на один із варіантів: правлення (дія),
>   виправлення (результат).
>
> НЕ РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО   *У тексті багато правок.  Правка тексту після машинного перекладу — копітка робота.*
>
> РЕКОМЕНДОВАНО *У тексті багато виправлень. Правлення тексту після машинного перекладу — копітка робота.*

Як правильно написати/побудувати речення - "Стаття "Сосна" потребує правок"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Правлення**](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) - дія за значенням **правити**,  [**виправлення**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vypravlennja) - дія за значенням **виправити**, в іншому значенні як:

> 2. Те, чим що-небудь замінене, виправлене. Перевидали [карту Сибіру] з деякими виправленнями і доповненнями (Видатні вітчизняні географи.., 1954, 16).

На мою думку правильно вживати : "Стаття "Сосна" потребує  виправлення. Оскільки слово **"правка"** в даному випадку означає результат, а не дію, тому його і варто замінити на відповідник за значенням дії.

Також слово Слово **правки** має також синонім [корективи](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0), яке за значенням тотожне [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/korektyv):

> **КОРЕКТИ́В**, у, чол. Часткова зміна або виправлення чого-небудь; **поправка**. Вже бачу, як ти хмуришся.. Але не бійся за мене, тут у мене є корективи (Леся Українка, V, 1956, 339); Хаєцький мав гострий зір, він.. до всього хотів вносити свої корективи (Олесь Гончар, III, 1959, 206); Андрій ознайомився з планом наведення переправи, вніс деякі корективи, і робота закипіла з новою силою.

Тому, вважаю, буде доречно: "Стаття "Сосна" потребує **коректив.**